# DocumentData / DocumentGroup initializes new instance of @ObservedObject on each change of the documents data in swift

Tags: swift, document-based

I'm trying to create a Document-Based App, where each new Document has an own instance of `Session()`, which should not be stored with the document data though:

```
DocumentGroup(newDocument: DocumentData()) { file in
   ContentView(document: file.$document, session: Session())
}
```

`Session()` is defined using

```
@MainActor
class Session : ObservableObject {
   @Published var sessionName:String? = nil
   @Published var sessionID = UUID()
   // some more to come
   init() {
      print("A new Session has been created: \(self.sessionID.description)
   }
}
```

Whenever I change something in the Document Data, a new instance of `Session()` is initiated. Every letter I type makes a new line of

> A new Session has been created: 2FCD7F9F-21D6-49BD-B00C-487D86064F08

It works when I do it like this:

```
@ObservedObject var session = Session()
DocumentGroup(newDocument: DocumentData()) { file in
   ContentView(document: file.$document, session: session)
}
```

This unfortunately creates one `Session()` for the whole App - so not one per document.

Mostly I'm wondering WHY this is happening - is this a wanted behavior or rather a bug?
It doesn't matter if I initiate the `Session()` in a subview, the result still stays the same. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Use `StateObject` to initialize not `ObservedObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the StateObject to ObservedObject

StateObject is used for initializing ObservableObjects and ObservedObject is usted to observed already initialized ObservableObjects